# File permissions on Shared hosts

Tags: apache, permissions, shared-hosting

I've written a script which takes the summary of an order and stores in into an XML file, except the problem is that I don't want people to be able to open the XML file in their browser, obviously.

I'm hosted on a very dodgy shared server with limited abilities: no SSH, for starters.

**Is there a place I can put this file so that PHP will still be able to read/write to it, but web browsers won't be able to get to it?**

Ordinarily, I'd create a folder outside the document root and put it there, but I get a "Permission denied" message when I try that.

The folders which *are* there are:

- anon_ftp
- bin
- cert
- cgi-bin
- conf
- error_docs
- etc
- httpdocs
- httpsdocs
- pd
- private
- statistics
- subdomains
- web_users

PHP can't access the file when it's in the `private` folder. Would this be possible using .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around it by putting the XML file in my httpdocs folder, but added a .htaccess file with this in it:

```
<Files ~ "myfile.xml">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could create a directory containing a `.htaccess` file that looks something like the following:

```
Deny from all
```

This will instruct Apache not to serve files from that directory; any attempts to access the directory or its contents will be met with a "403 Forbidden" response from the server.

**Note:** This depends upon the host not having removed `Limit` from the list of options in their `AllowOverride` directive; most shared hosts shouldn't have a reason to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you ask the shared-hosting provider to create an outside-web-root folder **for you**? I've certainly done this in the past.

Comment: you've obviously never been with WebAccess